# Angular JS - ng-repeat filter object array based on multiple object properties using the same ng-model

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of employees that look like

```
$scope.Arr = [
           {'name':'John','title':'CEO','Age':'32'}, 
           {'name':'Jill', 'title':'Sales Executive', 'Age':'44'},
           {'name':'Alex','title':'Developer','Age':24}
          ];
```

I use ng-repeat to render this array in html and am looking to make the filter work such that the same input control's value can be used to filter employees based on both the `name` as well as `title`.

```
<input type='text' data-ng-model='search.name' />

<div>
  <span data-ng-repeat="emp in Arr | filter:search">
  <p> {{emp.name}} </p>
  <p> {{emp.title}} </p>
  </span>
</div>
```

The above code only lets me filter on basis of employee name

Comment: You wanted to filter items based on what is given in the input box am I right? (not just name attribute)

Comment: Change it to `filter:search.name`. Note that it will compare the model value to all properties, not just name and title

Comment: @Swayam here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Fni3pDdOvYA8B7IpRCzD?p=preview. Simple use search.name in filter.

Comment: @squiroid @phil I am trying to filter emp based on both `name` and `title` with the `search` model. `search` instead of `search.name` works just fine

Comment: Can you please elaborate by some example .

Comment: @jan yes, I am trying to sort the array of employees based on the value in the input box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use filter to search based on both name and title.

The default angularjs filter on the expression "emp in Arr | filter: {name: $select.search, title: $select.search}" performs an AND between "name: $select.search" and "title: $select.search"

Write a custom filter to perform OR operation

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(names, title) {
        var output = [];

        if(angular.isArray(names)) {
            names.forEach(function(item) {
                var nameMatch = false;

                var keys = Object.keys(title);
                for(var i=0; i<keys.length; ++i) {
                    var t = keys[i];
                    var text = title[t].toLowerCase();
                    if(item[t].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1) {
                        nameMatch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(nameMatch) {
                    output.push(item);
                }
             });
          }
          else {
              output = names;
       }

       return output;
   };
});
```

Basically, this code lets you filter based on both name and title. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've made a plunker -> http://plnkr.co/edit/VzqvgYCesmsNRMWfEakk?p=preview .... I hope this is what you require. In the select box, you can search based on "name" and "title". 'demo.js' has the "customFilter" defined